# Черный экран при включении пк с видеокартой amd

Tags: amd, видеокарта, монитор, прошивка

Ребят, такая история случилась: покупал с Али видеокарту и комплект: материнская плата, оперативка и процессор. Все работает. Однако захотелось мне в Биос зайти. На моей старой видеокарте 750 TI все получалось, однако на новой с Али Amd Radeon Rx 580 2048SP не получается. При нажатии на Del такое ощущение, что заходит в Биос, но картинке на мониторе нет. Я предполагаю, что это связано как то с этой штукой на фотке (смотрел в Techpowerup GPU-Z). Кто-нибудь знает, как решить данную проблему, прошивать ли мне видеокарту и где брать прошивку, если придется делать это? Биос у меня старый не uefi[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/ - там брать прошивку, но не факт что на твою карту подойдёт биос от 580, Возможно у тебя франкенштейн и чип у неё чип стоит уже от 570 или 470. Видяха кстати вообще не показывает ничего или при загрузке виндовс отрубается? Если вообще не видит, то не факт, что она вообще работает, а если гаснет, то вполне возможно биос не тот. Остальные все запчасти нормально работают я так понял, раз при 750ti грузится всё норм.

Comment: Она работает в шиндовсе картинка есть, только загрузку самой системы и биос не показывает. Если брать прошивку, то эта галочка уберется с uefi или она вообще не влияет на загрузку биоса без uefi?

Comment: Попробуйте воткнуть в другой порт. А также отключить "CMS" в BIOS, зайдя с другой карты - если вообще там это есть. Вот [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/1522035/cant-get-into-the-bios-uefi-or-see-boot-output-on-displayport-but-can-on-hdmi) точно такая же проблема

Comment: Кабель питания вытащи, Батарейку из материнки вытащи и замени контакт на минуту, произойдет сброс Биоса на стандартные настройки, должно помочь

Comment: в настройках биоса поставил вот эту настройку - вкладка Advanced -> csm configuration -> video и поставил -> uefi
все заработало и картинка появилась